# Capture , if between substring ""

Tags: regex, regex-negation

```
(?!([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$),
```

This captures , if it is between "".Lets say the test string is

```
 1 2 3 4 , 5 6 7, 8 9 "10 11 12 , 13 14 15," 16,17,"18,19,"20 21,22
```

captured will be between 12 and 13 and rest like

```
  http://regex101.com/r/rX0dM7/1
```

Now if i change the same the to

```
(?!(.*?".*?")*[^"]*?$),
```

This captures only the end ,'s between 18 and 19.Something like

```
  http://regex101.com/r/hL7uS1/1
```

Now the question is why is [^"] so different from .*?" .

Secondly  what is the significance of [^"]*$ as if i remove it nothing gets captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, I think you are not thinking this correctly.

Lookarounds are centric about where the current search *Position* is.

In your lookahead, you are negatively matching the comma in an expression before it even finds the comma.

This is called overlap.

Lookahead's usually are inserted after a matched subexpession has been consumed, the position
increases then the assertion is checked.

Likewise, Lookbehinds typically go before the object subexpression.

So, your regex is actually this

```
 ,
 (?!
      ( [^"]* " [^"]* " )*
      [^"]* $ 
 )
```

When you do this, you can easily see that after removing `[^"]*$`
this `( [^"]* " [^"]* " )*` matches at every point in the string.
Because it is optional.

If you were to change it to `( [^"]* " [^"]* " )+` then it would find
something concrete to negatively match against.
The `$` was serving that purpose before.

Hope you have a better understanding now.

Comment: Thanx but when we replace by [^"]* by .*? it goes wrong.I m trying to understand that.Can you throw some light over it

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you are a novice. The dot meta char means [^\n], compared with [^"]. That's why. Classes are a basic regex construct. I suggest starting there to shed light on it.

Comment: yes i am learning through all those.My main question was [^"]* and (.*?)".When we use later ,how can it match " when it is set to lazy option.When it first encounters " it should stop .That was my concern

Comment: There is no need to overcomplicate things. It just gets you confused. The behavior of 'lazy` quantifiers can be overridden and be made to be temporarily greedy. The engine does this automatically. Its exhibited here -> `.*?"(?<!a")` only matches `aa"ccc"`. There is no other match, so the engine has no choice. Try not to be fooled by lazy quantifiers, we really, in making regex just _Suggest_ things to the engine. When you become a Zen in the future, you can use regex like a scalpel, until that time keep practicing.

Answer (score 3):

- `[^"]*"` matches any number of characters *except*  quotes, followed by a quote.
- `.*?"` matches any number of characters, *including* quotes, followed by a quote.

Now the `?` in the second regex makes the `*` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) lazy, which means that it asks it nicely to match as few characters as possible to make the match happen. Therefore, in the string `abc"def"`, both regexes will match the same text. So far, so good.

The problem is now that you've enclosed that regex in a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which has to make sure that the regex inside it is *impossible* to match. Since the dot *may*  also match a quote if it has to, it will do so in order to make a match possible, and that will cause the lookahead to fail unless there are only two quotes left in the string.

For your second question, `[^"]*$` makes sure that other characters besides quotes are allowed to appear at the end of the string.

Comment: you mean to say .*?" will match " too? will it skip the first "" to match the second "" ? and when i remove the second part why is there no match?

Comment: Yes, yes, and did you read the last sentence of my answer (and remember that we're inside a negative lookahead, so if we remove the end-of-string anchor, we remove the need for the regex to check the entire string for a match)?

Comment: If i remove $ or [^"]*$,then it doesnt match anything :(

Comment: i get everything now but the only thing left is how can .*? skip " tp match the end "".Is it designed that way?Is it documented somewhere?Conceptually it should not skip right?

Comment: For example, the first `.*?` can match `' 13 14 15,"'`, the second matches `' 16,17,"18,19,"'` (which is possible because `.` can match `"`), then `[^"]*?$` matches `'20 21,22'`, which causes the lookahead to fail - therefore the comma between `12` and `13` doesn't match.

Comment: Thanx a lot.I think am getting near it.