# Confusing RegEx results

Tags: json, regex

why is the following regex:

```
"_id":"(.+?)"}\],"componentType":"(.+?)"
```

for this string:

```
"name":"in","_id":"a05d91a7-6be0-c252-08e9-bf94cc0be36e","value":"5.6"}],"_id":"e986915c-22db-429f-9fe7-ae2e2ddfa779","refId":"de9ff045-21ce-4833-af34-30f50c129840","failId":"8b723736-a391-fd7e-8d23-7cc72e568f48"},{"outputs":[{"metadata":{"label":{"value":"Output Integer","capco":"U"},"desc":{"value":"Output
Integer.","capco":"U"}},"name":"f7018f5c-057c-6ab9-7300-875c712b87b7","_id":"daad7ae7-356b-57ca-037e-0c4bcb307201"}],"componentType":"model","metadata":{"signature":"ab7e00a928dc79af806b828e1831a95e","zOrder":1,"label":{"lang":"en","value":"BBBBBBBBBBB","capco":"U"},"geom":{"w":150,"x":203,"h":60,"y":324}
```

pulling everything from the a05d91a7 UUID to the componentType at the bottom, and not from the _id at the bottom?  I have (as far as I'm aware) nothing which indicates pulling additional content between the id (.+?) pattern and the componentType pattern?

What I'm trying to pull specifically is the following:

```
"_id":"daad7ae7-356b-57ca-037e-0c4bcb307201"}],"componentType":"model"
```

to be clear, the UUID is variable, hense the (.+?)

Comment: I think you need a regex like `"_id":"([^"]+?)"}],"componentType":"([^"]+?)"` ;).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use some json libraries to parse the input?

Comment: not familiar with what's available in java for json libraries, I'm building these queries in jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"_id":"([^"]*)"}],"componentType":"(.+?)"
```

Use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/38

The problem with your regex is `.*?`  can expand based on what condition it needs to match ahead.when you use `[^"]*` its a negation based approach and cannot go beyond a `"` in any case.

Comment: I understand what the above is doing, but to understand the mistake, why is the simple (.+?) within quotes not working?  what is it looking at that causes it to go to beyond the quotes, since ? is suppossed to make it not greedy?

Comment: @DavidTorrey it is non greedy but you have to provide regex a way to stop.The closing condition in this case is `"}],"componentType":"(.+?)"`  not just `"`.so it was capturing all

Comment: I don’t see any `.*?` anywhere in the original question and I assume `.*?` will work just as fine.

Comment: i see, that makes sense.  thanks.  I suppose I assumed it would stop at the first quotes then I could continue with more

Comment: @DavidTorrey yes...You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592796/capture-if-between-substring

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated JMeter Test Element - [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) which adds JSON support to JMeter.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) JMeter (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for details on the plugin installation and some JSONPath language reference - it is much simpler than regular expressions, less fragile and more human-readable