# capture multiple patterns in FIX messages

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to capture multiple patterns in messages as below:

```
line ="8=FIX.4.4^A9=0424^A35=W^A49=BROKER02^A56=FIRM01^A52=20120525-11:41:31.421^A34=000003^A55=USD/JPY^A262=1^A268=6^A269=0^A270=79.513^A271=500000^A299=869589960^A5020=20120529^A269=0^A270=79.511^A271=500000^A299=869589961^A5020=20120529^A269=0^A270=79.507^A271=1000000^A299=869589962^A5020=20120529^A269=1^A270=79.517^A271=500000^A299=869589963^A5020=20120529^A269=1^A270=79.519^A271=500000^A299=869589964^A5020=20120529^A269=1^A270=79.523^A271=1000000^A299=869589965^A5020=20120529^A10=191^A"

p1 = re.compile(r'(55=.*?)\^A') 
p2 = re.compile(r'(55=.*?)\^A+(299=.*?)\^A+(5020=.*?)\^A')
ret1 = re.findall(p1, line) 
ret2 = re.findall(p2, line)
```

For p1 and p2, I expect that ret1 should be identical to the first part of ret2. However, what I'm getting is:

```
['55=USD/JPY']
[('55=USD/JPY^A262=1^A268=6^A269=0^A270=79.513^A271=500000', '299=869589960', '5020=20120529')]
```

Why is this? Why the first portion captures more than ^A?
Thanks!

Comment: This does not make sense. `(55=.*?)\^A` does not match  `55=USD/JPY`

Answer (score 0):

> Why the first portion captures more than ^A?

This is because the terminating condition for `.*?` is not `^A` but `\^A+(299=.*?)\^A+(5020=.*?)\^A`.So it will not stop on first `^A` but it will temporarily move ahead and stop at the `^A` which has `299 etc` ahead of it.

[Read More Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592796/capture-if-between-substring)

You can achieve what you want by using

```
(55=.*?)\^A.+?(299=.*?)\^A+(5020=.*?)\^A
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/1)

Comment: Thank you! Now I modified to: p2 = re.compile(r'(55=.*?)\^A.*?(299=.*?)\^A.*?(5020=.*?)\^A'), and it is ok now.